# Mongo DB stoped responding taking long time to fetch or insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, mongodb-query

Working mongo db stopped suddenly,

I am using MongoDB, ip address is added successfuly and it was woking fine but suddemly twice in a day it stops some times it is too slow it takes many times to send get response. i have got log as below:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
......
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
......
reason: TopologyDescription {

type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
setName: 'atlas-x00t1p-shard-0',
maxSetVersion: 16,
maxElectionId: 7fffffff00000000000005b9,

servers: Map(3) {
'laksh-prod-shard-00-00.lubos.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'laksh-prod-shard-00-01.lubos.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'laksh-prod-shard-00-02.lubos.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
},

stale: false,
compatible: true,
compatibilityError: null,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
commonWireVersion: 17

}
```

using mongo db shared cluster :

CLUSTER TIER
M2 (General)
TYPE
Replica Set - 3 nodes
BACKUPS
Active

it happens some times only. some times i dont see these logs only not getting response from API which was working 5 min before. if i upgrade to dedicated server will it be resolved.

I want this issue to be solved. whether i need to upgrade or is it aws or mongodb issue

Comment: ips might be periodically changed

Comment: @dododo but it automatically worked after 5 mins. Using public IP from AWS instance will it change ?